# Find $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} n \sum ^{2n}_{k=n}\frac{1}{k^2} $.

Tags: measure-theory, riemann-sum, riemann-integration

I am supposed to do this question by defining a partition and then integrating, but I cannot thing of the way to do this. Please give me some steps and then I can apply this to other problems.

Find $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} n  \sum ^{2n}_{k=n}\frac{1}{k^2}  $.

Comment: This converges to $\int_1^2 \frac{1}{x^2} dx$.

Comment: Note $n\sum \frac{1}{k^2} = \sum \frac{1}{n} \frac{1}{\left(\frac kn\right)^2}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can write

$$n\sum_{k=n}^{2n}\frac1{k^2}=n\sum_{k=0}^n\frac1{(n+k)^2}=\frac1n\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac1{\left(1+\frac kn\right)^2}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\int_0^1\frac{dx}{(1+x)^2}$$

Comment: Cheers my dears!!!

Comment: That's the way!  (+1)